# GNOME system monitor and top showing different CPU usage

Tags: cpu-load, system-monitor, top, htop, mpv-media-player

When I play a movie with SMPlayer (video:mpv) and I check my CPU usage with GNOME system monitor, it shows %4 or %5 CPU usage (1 second update interval), but `htop` shows %45 CPU usage:

[image: mpv cpu usage]

`top` shows the same load as `htop`:

[image: top mpv cpu usage]

Since My CPU fan RPM goes higher when I'm playing movie with SMPlayer. I suspect `top` is reporting CPU usage more accurately.

I have Intel i7 920 with 6GB RAM.

Why do I have high CPU usage and why do I see different results on `top` and in GNOME system monitor?

Comment: when in `top`, press `1` to see percentages of individual cores

Comment: @thomasrutter Through my experience of working on servers, if you have a dual core running 100.00 your system is in major trouble and probably hanging.  There is a reason why we use 32+ core systems here as a lot of loaded systems will hit 25.00 in the 1 minute and above.  Even this one says that load average of 6.03 on a single core is bad, but on an 8 core is fine.  https://www.howtogeek.com/194642/understanding-the-load-average-on-linux-and-other-unix-like-systems/

Comment: @Terrance, I am aware that 100 load average is highly overloaded, just pointing out that it is possible. Your previous comment said load average on an 8 core machine could go up to 8.

Comment: @thomasrutter Yeah, I meant that as you would be fine.

Comment: This question is not even close to being a duplicate of that other one, what happened?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Notice that one reading is 8 times higher than the other.  You have 8 cores (or execution units).  The simplest explanation is that one is calculating it as a percentage of a single core, and the other as a percentage of all eight of them.

[According to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145247/understanding-cpu-while-running-top-command), `top` does indeed show CPU use per process as a percentage of a single CPU core.

Comment: This also explains why `top` can sometimes show processes using more than 100% CPU. On an 8 core CPU, up to 800% can be used