# MATE System Monitor does not display CPU usage correctly

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, cpu-load, system-monitor

I've noticed that the CPU usage display on Ubuntu MATE's built in system monitor (mate-system-monitor) does not display cpu usage correctly. The %CPU field appears to always display as all zeros (pictured in the middle). I found that gnome-system-monitor (pictured on the left) does at least appear to provide some information on CPU usage, even if the numbers are lower than expected (even lower than expected from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009829/gnome-system-monitor-and-top-showing-different-cpu-usage)).

Could it be something wrong with the config or launch flags of mate-system-monitor? Any idea how to fix this and get it to display %CPU correctly?

[image: Inconsistent CPU display. GNOME-system-monitor is on the left; MATE-system-monitor is in the middle; top is on the right.]

Comment: Go to View→All processes. Do you see changes?

Comment: That worked, thank you! I also had to disable the "Dependencies" checkbox to get them to sort correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to View → All processes and disable the "Dependencies" checkbox to get them to sort correctly.